# How to display geom_point like geom_bar in relation to x-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to display the geom_point side-by-side, excatly as it would be automatically displayed with geom_bar. I have tried several ways but couldn´t do it.

```
Q <- as_tibble(data.frame(series = rep(c("diax","diay"),3),
               value = c(3.25,3.30,3.31,3.36,3.38,3.42),
               year = c(2018,2018,2019,2019,2020,2020))) %>%
      select(year, series, value)


ggplot(data = Q, mapping = aes(x = year, y = value, color = series)) +
      geom_point(size = 8)
```

By running this code you'll find the chart below, which is centered in the x-axis point, instead of displaced as would be in geom_bar.

[image]

With geom_bar one could run the following code to get side-by-side bars for each x-axis point:

```
ggplot(Q, aes(year, value, fill = factor(series))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 1))
```

which renders the following chart

[image]

In case one is working with geom_tex, like the following:

```
ggplot(data = Q, mapping = aes(x = year, y = value, color = series, label = sprintf("%.2f",value))) +
  geom_point(size = 13) +
  geom_text(vjust = 0.4,color = "white", size = 4, fontface = "bold",show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

And try to apply position_doge, like this:

```
ggplot(data = Q, mapping = aes(x = year, y = value, color = series, label = sprintf("%.2f",value))) +
  geom_point(size = 13, position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  geom_text(vjust = 0.4,color = "white", size = 4, fontface = "bold", 
            position = position_dodge(width = 1), show.legend = FALSE)
```

The following happens:

[image]

But the curious thong is that the exactly the same logic works with geom_bar:

```
ggplot(Q, aes(year, value, fill = factor(series), label = sprintf("%.2f",value))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 1)) + 
  geom_text(color = "black", size = 4,fontface= "bold",
            position = position_dodge(width = 1), vjust = 0.4, show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

Does anyone know how to make position_dodge work as expected in the example above with geom_point?

Comment: So you want the points displaced by -0.25 and +0.25 relative to the their actual x-values? `ggplot(data = Q, mapping = aes(x = year, y = value, color = series)) +
  geom_point(size = 8, position=position_dodge(1))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: An additional question, is what if I had geom_text inside the points? the position = position_dodge(1) within the geom_text instruction works fine with geom_bar but it does not change the place of the text when together with geom_point, I will add the images...